# Android sqlite fts3 match and compare integer/float

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

We have a sqlite fts3 table without enhanced syntax(Android!!!) where we use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE tableName MATCH 'name*' AND validTo > 1389999600000 LIMIT 10
```

This works fine on iOS with fts4 and enhanced syntax, the validTo compare don't work as expected:

```
validTo > anyNumber => true
validTo < anyNumber => false
```

This has something to do with the that a full text search table contains strings. But then again - it works on iOS.
On iOS we have times with a decimal value like `1389999600000.0` but we have tried that without any change.

Any clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use FTS tables to store non-text data.

If you really want to treat data in an FTS table as a number, you have to convert it explicitly:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(validTo AS NUMERIC) > 1389999600000
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Well I think it is faster than a subselect.